# Using return value of constexpr function as parameter to another function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr

I have a `constexpr` function that computes CRC32 hash from string literal.

```
template <size_t len>
constexpr uint32_t ctcrc32(const char (&str)[len]) {
    return detail::crc32<len - 2>(str) ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

(it refers to other `constexpr` functions)

What I want to do is to call some other function that accepts `uint32_t` value and uses it to access data in some `unordered_map`. Such call looks like this:

```
uniformByNameCRC32(ctcrc32("uPointLight.position"));
```

I expect that `"uPointLight.position"`'s hash computes once at build time and then a resulting constant is passed to `uniformByNameCRC32()`, but that is not the case and `ctcrc32()` is called at runtime which kills CPU basically, since I have a lot of `uniformByNameCRC32()` calls.

This, however, works fine:

```
std::array<uint64_t, ctcrc32("string_literal")> array;
```

Such code compiles and indicates that `ctcrc32()`'s return value is indeed a `constexpr`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `ctcrc32` is not `constexpr`. It can't be when it odr-uses a reference parameter. A non-template function "constexpr" definition like this will be ill-formed. You only get away with it because for templates the constexpr is silently removed if the function body is invalid.

Comment: Are you using c++ 11, 14 or 17?

Comment: I'm using C++14

Comment: Ok. Why is ctcrc32's call result being accepted as a template argument though?

Comment: @ПавелМуратов - Can you post a true [mcve]? Something we can copy and paste and tinker with?

Comment: @StoryTeller I can do it in some online C++ editor/compiler, but how to know that function is evaluated at build time instead of run time?

Comment: @ПавелМуратов - you can impose "that function is evaluated at build time instead of run time" saving its return value in a `constexpr` variable; somethign like `constexpr auto val = ctcrc32("uPointLight.position"); uniformByNameCRC32(val);`

Comment: @max66 going to try that. Anyway, here is the sample code https://onlinegdb.com/r1TapkS0b

Comment: @ПавелМуратов - so I suppose you can write `constexpr auto fsc = ctcrc32("first_string"); constexpr auto ssc = ctcrc32("second_string");` and next `std::cout << globalMap[fsc] << std::endl; std::cout << globalMap[ssc] << std::endl;`

Comment: @max66 that's probably it. I wonder how to wrap it in some macro since I don't want to write two lines of code each time.

Comment: @ПавелМуратов - this is another question; I have an idea to avoid this problem (well... an half of an idea... and not a good one, I suppose) but I think you should approve the Jarod42's answer (that respond perfectly (as far I understand) to your question) and propose another question whith your full code.

Comment: @ПавелМуратов - sorry: I was wrong: your new requirement it's perfectly compatible with your actual question; added another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use intermediate constrexpr variable:

```
constexpr auto value = ctcrc32("uPointLight.position")
uniformByNameCRC32(value);
```

Comment: Thank you. This, however, doubles the amount of lines I have to write in such scenario :( Though I'm glad it is possible after all. I'll refactor my code and accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The OP ask (in a comment)

> how to wrap it in some macro since I don't want to write two lines of code each time

I suppose you can use a function that receive the `ctcrc32` value as template value and simply return it.

I mean

```
template <uint32_t N>
constexpr uint32_t getCV () // get constexpr value
 { return N; }
```

that you can use as follows

```
uniformByNameCRC32(getCV<ctcrc32("uPointLight.position")>());
```

Passing the `ctcrc32()` value to `getCV()` as template parameter force the compiler to calculate it compile time.

Comment: I use  a similar more generic method: `template<auto V> constexpr auto constexpr_v = V;`  resulting in `uniformByNameCRC32(constexpr_v<ctcrc32("uPointLight.position")>);`

Answer (score 3):

There are no guarantees anything is done at compile time vs run time in C++.  C++ in theory permits your code to be passed as a string literal to a C++ interpreter at runtime.  (There are some mandatory diagnostics for some ill-formed programs, but the form of said diagnostics is not specified, and you are permitted to emit a diagnostic even if there is no ill-formedness, so simply printing out a line saying "this code will be compiled later" satisified the standard).

`constexpr` simply lets you do some things in code that traditionally are done at compile time, like size arrays on the stack or use constants in the name of a type.

There are zero major C++ compilers which name new types at runtime.  So, we have an in to force something to run at compile time; in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) we have template constants:

```
template<uint32_t v>
std::integral_constant< uint32_t, v > kint32{};
```

With that, we can do:

```
uniformByNameCRC32(kint32<ctcrc32("uPointLight.position")>);
```

should execute `ctcrc32` at compile time.  Not doing so would require a *lot* of work by the compiler.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can even do:

```
template<auto x>
std::integral_constant< std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x > k{};
```

and it works for any type.

`std::integral_constant` in turn implicitly converts back to a value of the same type.

Comment: Great solution! A few minor notes, though: variable-length arrays are supported in numerous languages including C99 (no longer mandatory in C11) and Ada. Also, GCC supports them in C++ as an extension So "traditional" mostly applies to standard C++. Finally, it sounds very legalistic to say that the unconditional diagnostic "this code will be compiled later" satisfies the standard.

Comment: @ArneVogel I'm aware that languages that are not C++ have variable length arrays (this includes pseudo-C++ like microsoft/gcc extended-C++).  I was simply pointing out in theory that a C++ compiler that simply saved the source to be compiled later could satisify the standard.  I do get that "This code will be compiled later and any errors in compilation will occur as runtime errors" diagnostic is exploiting a vagueness in the standard, but the point remains.